# Search and Select in ArcPy with Cursors

Tags: python, gis, arcgis, python-2.5, arcpy

I'm working on a tool that identifies features and repairs them using an existing tool. At the moment I am struggling to put my idea into code however.
The purpose is to use a search cursor from a Select Features By Location layer to identify and then select features in the original data and execute another tool.
As of right now, my code looks something like this (in ArcMap 9.3):

```
Junctions_Lyr = "Junctions_Lyr"
gp.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Junctions, Junctions_Lyr, "", "", "")
gp.SelectLayerByLocation_management(Junctions_Lyr, "INTERSECT", Corrupt_Lyr, "", "NEW_SELECTION")
gp.SaveToLayerFile_management(Junctions_Lyr, "Junctions.lyr", Workspace)
rows = gp.SearchCursor(Junctions, "OBJECTID")
curs = gp.SearchCursor(Junctions_Lyr, "OBJECTID")
for row in rows:
    if row.OBJECTID = curs.OBJECTID:
        # Something to select the feature and run clean up tool.
        rows.next()
    else:
        rows.next()
```

Essentially, this will (hopefully) select features in the Junctions Feature class if they intersect with a corrupted layer. They will then be selected and saved to file. The original feature class will then have a search cursor run through it, and, if the Object ID matches with one from the Saved Layer file, it will select the feature and run the clean up tool.

Am I approaching this correctly? I think my inability to properly articulate this is making the issue a lot more difficult to resolve.

Comment: You might have more luck over here http://gis.stackexchange.com or here https://geonet.esri.com given the geographic nature of the data and software you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll make sure to post there as well.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's a good approach. But there are some possible improvements in your code that I can see:

- Though you do need to make a layer in memory to do the select, you don't need to save it as a layer file.
- You don't need to work with two different feature sets. Just select on the feature layer and use the selection set.
- `row.OBJECTID = curs.OBJECTID` is an assignment, not a comparison. Use `==` to compare, not `=`.
- If your repair tool can work with an entire set of features, then just give it the feature layer after you do the selection, and the selection should be honored. If your repair tool takes only one feature, you do need to run `SearchCursor` like you're doing (but only once). My sample below assumes that the repair tool takes only one feature at a time.

Here's some code that I think does what you need:

```
Junctions_Lyr = "Junctions_Lyr"
gp.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Junctions, Junctions_Lyr, "", "", "")
gp.SelectLayerByLocation_management(Junctions_Lyr, "INTERSECT", \
    Corrupt_Lyr, "", "NEW_SELECTION")
for row in gp.SearchCursor(Junctions_Lyr):
    pt = row.SHAPE.getPart(0)
    print("TODO run tool on selected feature " + str(row.OBJECTID) \
        + ", x = " + str(pt.X) + ", y = " + str(pt.Y))
```